# query in YouTrack that will display all issues that do not have a 'subtask of' relation?"

Tags: youtrack

How to make a query in YT that will display all issues **that do not have **a 'subtask of' relation?"

Ive treied:

#issues -Subtask of: (project: XYZ)

Youtrack: Incorrect query syntax: We couldn't find "Subtask".

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `has: -{Subtask of}`